# Renaming index.php in the htaccess in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to rename the index.php in the htaccess file which I used for removing the long url, I renamed index.php to main.php, this is because  of hacker overwriting my index.php.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  #Removes access to the system folder by users.
  #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php
  #controller, previously this would not have been possible.
  #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^CI_System.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cacworldwide/main.php?/$1 [L]
  #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
  #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends
  #the request to cacworldwide/main.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cacworldwide/main.php?/$1 [L]

 </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
   # can be sent to main.php, and everything works as normal.
   # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
   ErrorDocument 404 /cacworldwide/main.php
 </IfModule>
```

Comment: what problem are you facing. can you mention please.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, following lines would solve your problem

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cacworldwide/main.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```